# MailChimp content blocks drag&drop not working

Tags: mailchimp

I had to edit existing custom template in MailChimp service where drag&drop of content blocks isn't working. Template had a lot of nested tables so I contacted their support with response that some of block are nested and it might cause conflicts. To make simple test case scenario I removed most of code, styles and left just one repeatable block with one editable header inside.

I was doing everything as mentioned [in this part of documentation](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-work-with-repeatable-content-blocks#drag).

According to article, on edit screen after clicking on this double arrow some kind of yellow bar should popup but there was nothing happening. I tried to click and drag it.

**Question here is how make replicable and draggable content block on MailChimp.**

My code below.

```html
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" style="color: #fff;" marginheight="0" offset="0">
    <center>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                    <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-right:33px; padding-left:33px; text-align: left;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateLectures">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; font-size: 12px;">
                                            <h3 class="imagereplacement" style="text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;padding-bottom:10px;"><img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/42cd17e5e3c7c6f9274766dc5/images/lectures.png"><span style="display: block !important;">Lectures</span></h3>
                                            <div mc:repeatable="lecture" mc:variant="lecture" class="single_event">
                                                <h5 mc:edit="lecture_event_title">Koloman Moser In Context</h5>
                                                <h6>Thursday, May 23</h6>
                                                <p class="eventtitle">Christian Witt-Dörring</p>
                                                <p class="eventtext">Curator, Koloman Moser, Designing Modern Vienna 1897–1907</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

Save your template. After go in campings, create new camping, click next, after this choose your template, and after this you can drag your blocks and save changes if you want.
[image]