# Is it possible to code drag&drop templates for mailchimp?

Tags: email, templates, drag-and-drop, mailchimp

Seems like mailchimp has two types of templates: classic and "drag and drop."

The classic templates (they call these "themes") have content areas defined using the mc: attrubutes. Some of these can be repeated but can't be moved around.

The "drag and drop" templates have "container" zones which accept content blocks from a menu which appears only when the template is of the "drag and drop" kind.

Seems that it is impossible to code and import a "drag and drop" template. I tried exporting one of theirs to HTML but was given a warning that re-importing the template will eliminate its drag and drop functionality.

Am I correct in understanding that it is only possible to code and import "classic" templates using the mailchimp template tags or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you can, here my answer how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353570/mailchimp-content-blocks-dragdrop-not-working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use drag and drop, but it's not documented any where that I could find. I was able to get the source code they used to get the "content" and "design" panels to appear on the righthand side.

#### Code:

In order to get the "content" panel to appear you need to use code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/edesilets/e58c984bdaf307d1ff91e06fbe3c0119)! It's just the source code from the single column basic template. Paste the code into the "Edit Code" panel. You just need to follow the proper formatting in the file. **I haven't parsed through it yet to tell you what is exactly does what.**

#### Things you already knew.

The documentation on how to modify your templates (mc:edit="body") and have the design panel can be found here [MailChimp's Knowledge Base: Code Your Own](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/getting-started-with-mailchimps-template-language)

Answer (score 2):

I found edesilets' answer helpful.  I uploaded the [gist](https://gist.github.com/edesilets/e58c984bdaf307d1ff91e06fbe3c0119) file as a mailchimp template and started removing elements until I found what broke the drag and drop editor.

If you add the following code into your main content div or td it will enable the drag and drop block editor:

```
mc:container="body_container" mccontainer="body_container"
```

example:

```
<div  mc:container="body_container" mccontainer="body_container"></div>
```

This code will add a block editor region to the preheader section:

```
  mc:container="preheader_container" mccontainer="preheader_container"
```

For the header:

```
  mc:container="header_container" mccontainer="header_container"
```

For the footer:

```
 mc:container="footer_container" mccontainer="footer_container"
```

**Note:** It doesn't seem to matter what you call the mc:container.  Creating a new container with a different name worked.  Although using just mc:container tag seems to work at first by itself, the mccontainer (no colon) tag is required for it to save properly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, they did not like people to use this...
When you save the code using their backend, they will now strip out the mccontainer="footer_container" attribute and so you will no longer be able to see the elements you added using the "design" mode in the preview or the rendered email.

As an example, this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <body>
    <h1>I'm super simple</h1>
    <div mc:container="footer_container" mccontainer="footer_container"></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Will get this after you save the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <body>
    <h1>I'm super simple</h1>
    <div mc:container="footer_container"></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So you can edit the template using the drag and drop feature, but you will not see any results in the rendered email...

[image: The preview is empty]

Comment: It seems that this may not be entirely 100% accurate. If you use the code template that MailChimp gives you and then edit that by adding @createscape's information on the TD's it seems to work.